# iperf transfer & bandwidth output is garbage on Windows 7

Tags: windows, networking

I'm trying to run an iperf session between Windows-7 64bit laptop, through wireless AP, to iPad running iperf server.

At Windows, I type:
iperf -c 10.31.186.128  -p 5201  -t 1

...and get this output with bad (garbage) transfer and bandwidth:

### C:\PRIMARY_INSTALL\iPerf 2.0.5 as of 4-21-2015>iperf -c 10.31.186.128  -p 5201  -t 1

Client connecting to 10.31.186.128, TCP port 5201

### TCP window size: 63.0 KByte (default)

[  3] local 10.31.186.191 port 51730 connected with 10.31.186.128 port 5201
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0- 1.0 sec  64909840858359 bits  6572394324026484130271096932523s/sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that those tools were incompatible.

The following solution works...

IPAD IOS7 CLIENT & WINDOWS-7 SERVER:
1.  Install to Windows:  iPerf v2 command line tool from:
https://iperf.fr/

2. Enter directory with iperf.exe
3. Run:  iperf –s
   ..which starts service at port 5001.
4. Install and run “HE.NET Network Tools..” app onto iPad.
5. Select:  “iPerf2” for client
   (iPerf3 is not backward compatible with 2)
6. Enter IP of laptop.
   Data rate shown at both ends.